# What is fbevents_telemetry?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Sometimes I see my app, which has fb sdk, sent data to facebook with api:

**url**: `https://connect.facebook.net/log/fbevents_telemetry/`

**method**: POST.

and the **response status code is 400**. Does anyone know when it triggers this?

Thanks.